# How can I read the the dimension of a picture when I open it?

Tags: javascript

I'm making an application that can apply a filter on a picture. I set up the canvas 800 * 500, so when I upload an image bigger, the image is cropped.

How to read the dimension when I upload an image and then set up the dimension of the canvas before to copy the image on the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
*uploading code*  
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.onload = ()=>{var height=this.height;
                      var width=this.width;  };
```

Set these values as canvas dimensions

Comment: img.addEventListener("load", function () {
                            canvas.height = img.height;
                            canvas.width = img.width;                            
                            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                        });

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are using method

```
function el(id) 
{ 
   return document.getElementById(id); // Get elem by ID 
} 

el("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

You might edit it as this:

```
function el(id) 
{ 
       var element = document.getElementById(id); // Get elem by ID 
       element.height=this.height;
       element.width=this.width;
       return element;
} 
el("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

In javascript `this` keyword refers to global object

By default the execution context for an execution is global which means that if a code is being executed as part of a simple function call then “`this`” refers to global object.

That means element which invokend/triggered method will have its values stored in "this" keyword, and properties you are looking for are height and width.. :)

You could also incude jQuery here as of jQuery 1.2.6+ you can use one of the core CSS functions, height and width (or outerHeight and outerWidth, as appropriate).

```
var height = $("#element").height();
var width = $("#element").width();
```

p.s I saw in your code `readImage` is your event handler and I can't see it invoked anywhere..

Comment: This is my first question and I'm trying to figure out how exactly it works everything. I got two negative vote and I don't understand exactly why. Btw I tried to post my entire code before (where I invoke readImage) but it was blocked because to long. Next question I'll be more precise. Thank you very much for your answer, it was very helpful.

Comment: @I.Vacca If it was helpful for you please accept it as answer / vote up, thanks

Comment: I did it, thanks but as a new contributor my vote is not showed. Btw it is counted.